# MYSQL Join Left Condition does not work

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have this example of my problem:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0cc41/1/0

Description:
There are three tables (events, persons and user). The table persons connects events and user. persons.type_id is the events.id and persons.user_id is user.id. I created two events (id 1 and 2). There are one entry in person for each event.

My Sql:

```
SELECT events.*, 
coalesce(part_person.Accept_Participants_LJ, 0) AS Accept_Participants
FROM events 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(part_user.forname, ' ', part_user.surname) SEPARATOR ', ') AS Accept_Participants_LJ,
    part_person.type_id
    FROM persons AS part_person
    LEFT JOIN user AS part_user ON part_user.id = part_person.user_id 
    WHERE part_person.type = 'event_participant'
) part_person ON events.id = part_person.type_id
GROUP BY events.id
```

My expectation was:

```
------------------------
|id|Accept_Participants|
------------------------
|1 | Carl Habicht      |
------------------------
|2 | Peter Zwegert     |
------------------------
```

As you can see, the result is:

```
----------------------------------
|id| Accept_Participants         | 
----------------------------------
|1 | Carl Habicht,  Peter Zwegert|
----------------------------------
|2 | 0                           |
----------------------------------
```

It seems, that he ignores the ON-Condition of the Left Join.

But, where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group_concat should (almost) always have a group by and group by without any aggregation is not useful
Maybe this is what you need

```
SELECT events.*, 
coalesce(part_person.Accept_Participants_LJ, 0) AS Accept_Participants
FROM events 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(part_user.forname, ' ', part_user.surname) SEPARATOR ', ') AS Accept_Participants_LJ,
    part_person.type_id
    FROM persons AS part_person
    LEFT JOIN user AS part_user ON part_user.id = part_person.user_id 
    WHERE part_person.type = 'event_participant'
    group by part_person.type_id 
) part_person ON events.id = part_person.type_id
order  BY events.id
```